# Retrieve Visual Studio settings after synchronization wrong way

Tags: visual-studio, synchronization, settings

I recently logged into a different VS2022 on a different machine with my VS account. Settings didn't sync, unfortunately, and subsequently I tweaked a few manually.

Then later I logged in into my default VS2022 instance, and now the settings *did* sync (from that one-time VS2022 log-in to my main one), removing pretty much all the settings I had.

Does VS back-up settings somewhere? I can't find it, so I fear the answer is no :(

- The folder `%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Settings` did not exist for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did find old settings in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_xxxxxxxx\Settings`. Although they're half a year old in my case, they'll do.